# How to use while loop in CASE statements?

Tags: sql, for-loop, while-loop, case

I'm trying to divide the column "score" from 10 to 210 by intervals of 20. My current code is below, it's essentially assigning a range to each score. But is there a way to use while loop with the CASE statement to simplify the query?

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN score <= 10 THEN '10'
           WHEN score BETWEEN 11 AND 30 THEN '11-30'
           WHEN score BETWEEN 31 AND 50 THEN '31-50'
           ...
           WHEN score BETWEEN 191 AND 210 THEN '191-210'
END AS Score_range
```

Comment: How about `SELECT score % 20`

Comment: @juergend: How does that help? For example, if `score` is 200, then `score % 20` equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `score` is an integer, you can simplify your CASE statement using a bit of math:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN score <= 10 THEN '10'
    ELSE
        CONVERT(varchar, (score + 9) / 20 * 20 - 9) +
        '-' +
        CONVERT(varchar, (score + 9) / 20 * 20 + 10)
END AS Score_range
```

Here's how the formula works out for select values of `score`:

```
score  (score + 9)  (score + 9)/20 * 20  (score + 9)/20 * 20 - 9  (score + 9)/20 * 20 + 10
-----  -----------  -------------------  -----------------------  ------------------------
  11        20               20                      11                      30
  12        21               20                      11                      30
 ...       ...              ...                     ...                     ...
  29        38               20                      11                      30
  30        39               20                      11                      30
  31        40               40                      31                      50
  32        41               40                      31                      50
 ...       ...              ...                     ...                     ...
 209       218              200                     191                     210
 210       219              200                     191                     210
```

Note that `(score + 9) / 20 * 20` rounds `(score + 9)` down to the nearest multiple of 20.

Comment: This answer uses SQL Server syntax. For other SQL dialects, some minor adjustments will be needed.